# How do I query the DB when the dbPath is not default? MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Previously I had been connecting to my db like this:

```
const db = 'mongodb://localhost/dbname';    

mongoose.connect(db, {
  useMongoClient: true
});
```

After following along with a tutorial, I decided to change where my logs and db is stored. I changed my connection to:

```
const db = 'mongodb://localhost:5000';

mongoose.connect(db, {
  useMongoClient: true
});
```

And I created a mongod.conf:

```
# where to write logging data
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /Users/matt/mongodb/sampledb/logs/mongod.log

# Where and how to store data
storage:
  dbPath: /Users/matt/mongodb/sampledb/data/db
  journal:
    enabled: true

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 5000
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1
```

Now when I "show dbs" from the mongo shell, I am not sure "use" the db to query it. I figure I am missing a step somewhere.

Comment: `dbPath` has nothing to to with client interfaces or "database namespacing" in general at all. It's just a setting of the server process that determines the "physical location" of where the server files are stored. This has "zero" impact on your end application.

Comment: @NeilLunn That makes sense. I edited my question to include my new connection. Is my issue related to not having dbname after localhost:5000?

Comment: Looks like it. The format of the URI is basically `"mongodb://<user>:<password>@<host>:<port>/<database>"` And the full description is [in the manual](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/). If you don't specify a database namespace then `"test"` is used by default. Just as `localhost:27017` is presumed the default if not URI is provided at all.

Comment: @NeilLunn Since I am able to save and retrieve documents using this setup, where are they saving to?

Comment: I already told you what the default namespace is.

Comment: @NeilLunn Turns out my problem was 2 fold. I needed to use a db name in the connection string (or use the default like you said) as well as use the --port command line option when starting the shell.

Comment: Dude. `mongo 'mongodb://localhost:5000/dbname'` has been valid for a very long time. The shell is build on a driver afterall.

Comment: Clearly this was a very beginner question. I didn't realize I could access it like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was my that I was using a non-default port. So instead of starting the mongo shell with:

```
mongo
```

I needed to start it with:

```
mongo --port 5000
```

I also added a name to my db in the connection:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:5000:/dbname', {
  useMongoClient: true
});
```